# How do I duplicate the string stored in a strtok() token?

Tags: c, strtok

I'm trying to duplicate the value of a `strtok()` token.

I'm running `strtok()` on a `string` with `volatile` value.

```
char buffer[100];
char temp[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    fgets(buffer, 100, my_file);
    fscanf(my_file, "%s", temp)
}
```

An example value for temp in this case might be "100,200,300"

```
char my_array[3][100];
char* token;
token = strtok(temp,",");
while(token != NULL){
    switch (token[0]){
        case '1' :
        strcpy(my_array[0], token);
        break;
        case '2' :
        strcpy(my_array[1], token);
        break;
        case '3' :
        strcpy(my_array[2], token);
        break;
    }
    token = strtok(NULL,",");
}
```

What i'm attempting to do with `strcpy()` is to duplicate the value of the token, and store the duplicate value in an array.

Comment: `'1'` and `1` are not the same. You need the `case` to use the former not the latter.

Comment: `"100"` requires four bytes to store - three ascii characters plus a terminating NUL. Your array is too small and copying a string to it will cause a buffer overflow.

Comment: Seems you are missing `token = strtok(NULL,",");` after the switch-statement to get the next token

Comment: The simplest answer to the question is often `strdup()`, if it is available to you.  If it isn't, write it: `char *strdup(const char *str) { size_t len = strlen(str); char *dup = malloc(len + 1); if (dup != 0) memmove(dup, str, len + 1); return dup; }` — and watch people shout about `memcpy()` vs `memmove()`. —— However, what you've got should more or less work as long as the tokens start with a digit 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting your code into an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), I get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char temp[] = "100,200,300";
    char my_array[3][100];
    char *token = strtok(temp, ",");

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        switch (token[0])
        {
        case '1':
            strcpy(my_array[0], token);
            break;
        case '2':
            strcpy(my_array[1], token);
            break;
        case '3':
            strcpy(my_array[2], token);
            break;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%d: [%s]\n", i, my_array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from running that is:

```
0: [100]
1: [200]
2: [300]
```

It is not clear what your problem with your code is.

This is clearly not a general solution.  It relies on the three tokens starting with the three digits 1, 2, 3 — and on there being exactly 3 tokens, and none of the tokens being longer than 99 characters, and so on.  But your code safely copies the tokens into your array.

This is more general code, using the POSIX (but not C) standard function [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char temp[] = "100,200,300,19231,Exploratorium,Extraneous material,91"
                  "9293,and one rather long token without much significance"
                  " except to point out that not all strings are as short as"
                  " 100 bytes long";
    char *my_array[100];
    int count = 0;

    char *token = strtok(temp, ",");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (count >= 100)
            break;
        my_array[count++] = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        printf("%d: [%zu][%s]\n", i, strlen(my_array[i]), my_array[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        free(my_array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the output:

```
0: [3][100]
1: [3][200]
2: [3][300]
3: [5][19231]
4: [13][Exploratorium]
5: [19][Extraneous material]
6: [6][919293]
7: [123][and one rather long token without much significance except to point out that not all strings are as short as 100 bytes long]
```